# What is a set of functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I know that you can find the number of functions that map $A \to B$ through $|B|^{|A|}$, but I don't understand how this works? If $A={1,2,3}$ and $B={h,t}$, and for every element in $B$, there are $3$ elements in $A$ that it maps to, then it sounds like the answer is $6$, but the actual answer is $8= 2^3$. This just doesn't make sense... Can someone explain this to me?

Also, how would you write a a set of functions? Would it be a set of ordered pairs? If so, then wouldn't the answer be:
$\{{(h,1), (h,2), (h,3), (t,1), (t,2), (t,3)\}}$

Comment: When you said "for every element in B, there are 3 elements in A that it maps to" you were counting the number of functions *from B to A*, which is a different question. The answer is not the $3+3=6$ that you said, but $3×3=9$, because for *each* of the three possible choices for $f(h)$, there are three possible choices for $f(t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the eight(!) functions $A\to B$:

$$ 1\mapsto h, 2\mapsto h, 3\mapsto h$$
$$ 1\mapsto h, 2\mapsto h, 3\mapsto t$$
$$ 1\mapsto h, 2\mapsto t, 3\mapsto h$$
$$ 1\mapsto h, 2\mapsto t, 3\mapsto t$$
$$ 1\mapsto t, 2\mapsto h, 3\mapsto h$$
$$ 1\mapsto t, 2\mapsto h, 3\mapsto t$$
$$ 1\mapsto t, 2\mapsto t, 3\mapsto h$$
$$ 1\mapsto t, 2\mapsto t, 3\mapsto t$$

I guess you can see now why theoir cout is $|B|^{|A|}=2^3=8$.

---

A function $A\to B$ is especially a relation, i.e. a subset of $A\times B$. For example the third function in the list above  (more precisely its graph) is $\{(1,h),(2,t),(3,h)\}$. The set of all functions $A\to B$ can be thus written very unreadably this way if you like: $$\bigl\{\{(1,h),(2,h),(3,h)\},\{(1,h),(2,h),(3,t)\},\ldots, \{(1,t),(2,t),(3,t)\}\bigr\} $$

Comment: This and Emin's answer finally made it clear.

Answer (score 2):

For those given sets the set of all functions would be:
A-->B={{(1,h),(2,h),(3,h)};{(1,h),(2,h),(3,t)};...;{(1,t),(2,t),(3,t)}} and the set A-->B has 8 elements.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ 'sends' each element of $A$ to an element $f(a)$ of $B$. If $a\in A$ and set $B$ is finite with cardinality $|B|$ then there are $|B|$ choices for $f(a)$. This is true for every element of $A$ so if $A$ is finite also, and has cardinality $|A|$ then you come to $|B|\times |B|\times\cdots\times |B|=|B|^{|A|}$ choices.

The set of functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted as $B^A$.

Note that - if the sets are finite - you have $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$